# A different way to define homomorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V(K)$ and $W(k)$ be two vector space, and $f:V \to W$ an homomorphism.

Then $f$ maps subspaces in subspaces, forwards and backwards:
$$A \in \Sigma[V] \Longrightarrow f(A)\in \Sigma[W]$$
$$A \in \Sigma[W] \Longrightarrow f^{-1}(A)\in \Sigma[V]$$
My question is: do these conditions fully characterize homomorphisms ?
Otherwise stated, do they imply that $f \in Hom(V,W)$ ?

That's my try to prove the thesis.

Let
$$[v_1, ... , v_n]$$
a set of vectors in $V$ .
To prove that
$$f(k^{p}v_{p})=h^{p}f(v_{p})$$
consider 
$$M:=<[v_1, ... , v_n]>$$
$$N:=<[f(v_1), ... , f(v_n)]>$$
$$T:=f(M)$$
$$S:=f^{-1}(N)$$

Obviously
$$f(k^{p}v_{p}) \in T$$
From the first hypothesis
$$h^{p}f(v_{p}) \in T$$
Now, again from the fist hypotesis,
$$\Delta := f(k^{p}v_{p})- h^{p}f(v_{p}) \in T$$
and I would like, using the second one, prove that $\Delta = 0$ .
I'm grateful for your attention and I will greatly esteem any hint!

Comment: If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ maps forward and backwards subspaces, then is $f$ an homomorfism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $V$ and $W$ are both $1$-dimensional, e.g. $V=W=k$ then the only subspaces are $\{0\}\subset k$ and $k \subseteq k$.
Thus your conditions on a function $f\colon V\to W$ translate to:

1. $f(0)=0$ (since $f(\{0\})=k$ is impossible)
2. $f^{-1}(\{0\})=\{0\}$ or $f^{-1}(\{0\})=k$
3. $f(k)=k$ or $f(k)=\{0\}$
4. $f^{-1}(k)=k$ (since $f^{-1}(k)=\{0\}$ is impossible)

These are precisely the function $f\colon k\to k$ such that

- $f=0$ or
- $f(0)=0$ and $f\colon k\setminus \{0\}\to k\setminus\{0\}$ is any surjective function

Clearly not every such function is a homomorphism (unless $k=\mathbb{F}_2$).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply !! $F_2$ refers to the characteristic of the field $k$, doesn't it ?

Comment: $F_2$ is the field with precisely two elements. This field does in fact have characteristic $2$.